# Integrating Trx to html code in C# unit test case

Tags: c#, html, unit-testing, mstest, trx

I am a new learner of C# so my question may be irrelevant. I have written a test suite in C# but the summary report gets created as .trx file. I have another tool to convert .trx to .html file. Can anybody tell me how can i integrate the tool in C# test project so that the result of testing can also be saved as .html file?

I did some trial and error but found no solution as .trx is created once the testing is over and no more execution of methods are left. So i am not able to call the trxConverter class also.

Your valuable suggestions are required.

Comment: This would usually be done as a step in a build process, where you would update your code, build it, run the tests, format the results... do other build steps...

Answer (score 0):

I dont have the privilege for adding comments but anyways if I get you correctly, are you using OpenCover or part Cover to get your test summary because those are the ones that create .trx files for the test report in C# . If thats the case than you can simple change your code to read the input .trx file in the location that it is created and than easily write some C# code to get the HTML file. I have myself written a small tool in C# in the past that converted the OpenCover and partcover results into HTML file for me. So you dont have the overhead of an additional tool as well since everything can be done in C#

Comment: @Meghaa..Thanks for the comment... As you are now aware that i am new to C# so want to tell that  i have least knowledge of Open cover and part cover testing.. Moreover i am using Visual Studio to run the test case. Where can i find the code where .trx is getting generated?

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly r u using to get the .trx file and which version of visual sudio r u using

Comment: I am using MSTest to get the .trx file and it is Visual Studio 2010.